# Показательная функция в C++

Tags: c++

скажите, пожалуйста, каким образом вводится показательная функция в C++?
Задача стоит такая, найти корни уравнения x^2/2-10+2^(-x)=0 методом дихотомии.
Единственная проблема с вводом этой показательной функции 2^(-x). Буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что проблема в вычислении значения этой функции.

Используйте функцию [pow](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/pow-powf-powl?view=msvc-160)

```
#include <math.h>

z = pow(2.0, -x);
```

Answer (score 1):

В C++11 [доступна](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/exp2) также функция `exp2`. Она может работать быстрее, чем `pow(2.0,x)`